# Disable Woocommerce order notification for orders with a custom attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good day! I am looking to disable Woocommerce new order notification for orders that are synced in from other platforms as they are already automatically marked as completed. Currently, I am receiving new order notification from all the imported orders. These orders has its own custom fields.

Is it possible to make use of a hook to write a custom code to prevent new order notification email to admin for orders with the attribute ced_shopee_order_shop_id OR ced_lazada_seller_id?

[image: Custom Fields for Shopee order]
[image: Custom Fields for Lazada order]

I would still like to receive email notification for orders make on my website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Currently, I have modified the code given by Víctor Calderón but it does not work for my case.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'disable_notification_based_on_id', 10, 2);

function disable_notification_based_on_id($recipient, $order) {

    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ('wc-settings' === $page) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    if (!$order instanceof WC_Order) {
        return $recipient;
    }
    $items = $order -> get_items();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $shopee_id = $item['ced_shopee_order_shop_id'];
        $lazada_id = $item['ced_lazada_seller_id'];
        if ($shopee_id == 377700604 || $lazada_id == 1143399005) {
            $recipient = '';
        }
        return $recipient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to disable notification based on product id(in my case was product id 5274) so you should try to change $item['product_id'] with ced_shopee_order_shop_id OR ced_lazada_seller_id that matches your values

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'disable_notification_based_on_id', 10, 2);
function disable_notification_based_on_id($recipient, $order)
{
    
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ('wc-settings' === $page) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    if (!$order instanceof WC_Order) {
        return $recipient;
    }
    //this is the example for product id==5274, change the value to your atribute
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];// change to your atribute ced_shopee_order_shop_id OR ced_lazada_seller_id
        if ($product_id == 5274) {
            $recipient = '';
        }//change if condition to match your ced_shopee_order_shop_id OR ced_lazada_seller_id value
        return $recipient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor, I have modified your code to use my attributes but it is not working. Any chance you know what could go wrong? Really thankful for the above code to work with:)

Comment: If you provide more details about the error we could probably fix it